# Spring Boot + Security loadByUserName not passing userName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring security + spring JWT + Spring JPA to authenticate user. I have a rest end point /authenticate which authenticates the user via Authentication manager. Spring security createAuthenticationToken() calls loadByUserName(String UserName). But when I debug its printing NONE_PROVIDED
See my below code

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=UsersRepo.class)
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.ws"})

 public class TestWebApp{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestWebApp.class, args);
 }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class HelloResource {
@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
UserDeatilService userDeatilService;

@Autowired
JwtUtils jwtUtils;

@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody Users authenticationRequest) throws Exception{


authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));

    final UserDetails userDetails=userDeatilService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    
    final String jwt=jwtUtils.generateToken(userDetails);
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
 public class UserDeatilService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
UsersRepo userRepo;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("inside loadUserByUsername::"+username);
    
    Optional<Users> user=userRepo.findByUserName(username); 
    
    user.orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: "+username));
    
    return user.map(MyUserDetail::new).get();
   }
 }
```

SecurityConfigurer

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Securityconfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDeatilService  userDeatilService;

/*@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;*/

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDeatilService);
}


//Dont manage session
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
     //http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**").hasAnyRole("h2").antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    /*.and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);*/
    
    
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/authenticate").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER").antMatchers("/").permitAll().and().formLogin();
    
}



@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Repository

```
  @Repository
  public interface UsersRepo extends JpaRepository<Users,Integer>{
     Optional<Users> findByUserName(String username);
  }
```

MyUesrDetails

```
public class MyUserDetail implements UserDetails{

private String username;
private String password;
private boolean active;
private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;


public MyUserDetail(Users user) {
    this.username=user.getUsername();
    this.password=user.getPassword();
    this.active=user.isActive();
    this.authorities=Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(",")).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public MyUserDetail() {
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return active;
}}
```

Comment: Where did you implement Spring's UserDetailsService ? Spring will try to invoke the loadUserByUsername from It's UserDetailsService interface. You have to implement that interface and set as user details service in security config. Override loadUserByUsername there and write logic to load user by the username that you're passing from Authenticationmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exception says:

"No property userName found for type Users! Did you mean 'username'".

In your repository you declared a function called findByUserName and should be findByUsername, because you defined this attribute of MyUserDeatails as username not userName, is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all is eplained in your exception:

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDeatilService';

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDeatilService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo';

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepo' defined in com.barsamin.ws.repo.UsersRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BarsaminWebApplication:

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Failed to create query for method public abstract **java.util.Optional com.barsamin.ws.repo.UsersRepo.findByUserName(java.lang.String)**!

**No property userName found for type Users! Did you mean 'username'?**

Comment: So what's the mistake here

Comment: See in bold above